# Unwanted influence of Grid Default Style on ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, styles

In my project I have set the default background of the Grid to a custom Brush:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource StandardColor}"/>
</Style>
```

My ContextMenu then looks like this: [image: with Grid Default Style]. Note the strange separator!

And also: there is no behaviour on mouseover!

When I remove the Style above I get the mouseover behaviour (light-blue hover) and the ContextMenu looks like this: [image]. Correct!

But I still need the Grid background color.
So I was wondering whether I overlook something in the Style definition (I tried OverridesDefaultStyle=False but that doesn't change anything).
Also I cannot understand how the Style definition influences the mouse triggers?

Comment: What color is StandardColor? Is that value null???

Comment: No, it is a `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardColor" Color="OldLace" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears when you forget to consider dependency property value precedence.

Here is a link to the msdn page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Can someone please explain the solution because I'm not getting it from these two sentences?

Comment: @Sheridan The local value which was OldLace was always taking the precedence.. Local values always have higher priority.

Comment: Huh... good catch. It's a little bit strange though, because when I tried to recreate @Gerard's problem, I couldn't. It must have been the way he set his `Style`s or something.

Comment: I havent tried it out I just read the trigger wasnt able to change the color to light blue. My first thought was value precedence. Maybe I was wrong and he solved it on its own way. Who knows why he marked it as answered...